# [ReadyAPI]: Connect to Database in Groovy script

Tags: soapui, ready-api

Need help:
Upgraded my ReadyAPI to 2.3 version from 2.0. I have groovy script to connect to Databases defined at project level. It is throwing following error as below after upgrade.

**Error:**

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method:
>   com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.connections.DefaultDatabaseConnectionContainer.getDatabaseConnectionByName()
>   is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [MyDB]
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:58)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassSite.call(PojoMetaClassSite.java:49)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
>       at Script3.run(Script3.groovy:11)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:98)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory$SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIProGroovyScriptEngineFactory.java:82)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.runScript(WsdlTestCase.java:984)
>       at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.runSetupScript(WsdlTestCase.java:989)
>       ... 9 more

**My Script:**

```
import groovy.sql.Sql
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
def rbConObj = context.testCase.testSuite.project.databaseConnectionContainer.getDatabaseConnectionByName("MyDB");
def rbconstring = rbConObj.getConnectionString();
def sql = Sql.newInstance(rbconstring);
sql.executeUpdate("UPDATE Table SET Column = 2 Where ID = 1505")
```

Comment: Which jdbc driver are you using? jtds?

Comment: Placed error in quotes.

Comment: I have been using Microsoft SQL JDBC Driver driver. 
https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/data-driven/drivers/install/mssql.html

Answer (score 2):

A comment in the SmartBear support forums says `DatabaseConnectionContainer` has been deprecated in version 2.2, but I don't think that's right. The method `getDatabaseConnectionByName` has been refactored to `getResourceByName`. That will work better.